# push to mercurial windows client to linux server .dirstate

Tags: linux, samba, mercurial

When pushing mercurial project from Windows client to Linux server (via mapped drive), I get an access denied error.  I find a .dirstate-xxxx folder in servers .hg directory.  This has odd group and owner.

Any suggestions?